# How to install latest version of python 3.9.5 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python

I updated my system using:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then ran the following to install `python3.9`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.9
```

Which yields output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3.9 is already the newest version (3.9.5-3~20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

However, when I run `python3 -V` it still tells me I am on 3.8.5. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can run `python3.9` with the command

```
python3.9
```

(instead of the command `python` or `python3`)

It is *not* a good idea to change the default version of `python3` to `python3.9`, as that may break your Ubuntu installation. Instead, manually call it with `python3.9`.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to explicitly specifying the `python3.9` and working with it globally as explained in [Archisman Panigrahi answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1347778) ... You can create an **isolated virtual environment** where `python3 -V` will report `Python 3.9`.

This feature can be installed for Python3 like so:

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

To make a **Python3.9** virtual environment, you would first create a directory and `cd` to it like so:

```
mkdir my_env && cd my_env
```

Then, create a new **Python3.9 virtual environment** inside the directory like so:

```
python3.9 -m venv env
```

To use this environment, activate it like so:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Your shell prompt will show `(env)` like so:

```
(env) $
```

During this, `python3 -V` will report `Python 3.9` and commands, module installs or modifications will be contained locally in this virtual environment.

When you are done, deactivate this **Python3.9** virtual environment like so:

```
deactivate
```

Comment: i have installed python3.11, but python3.11 -m venv env failed with Error: Command '['/home/<user>/python3.11-venv/env/bin/python3.11', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
to fix it, i needed to install the corresponding venv package 'sudo apt install python3.11-venv'. See also this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594088/error-when-creating-venv-error-command-im-ensurepip-upgrade-def

Comment: @rome For Python3.11 please see https://askubuntu.com/a/1443735

Answer (score 4):

Consider installing Python with [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) or [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#linux-installers) (I recommend Miniconda). Conda lets you manage different Python versions easily with virtual environments.

`sudo wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`

`sudo chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`

`./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`

Press enter until it asks for "yes" or "no", then type "yes" to accept the terms of use.

If you're using a shell other than bash, type:

`conda init <SHELL_NAME>` (Supported shells include: fish, tcsh, xonsh, zsh)

Close and open the terminal. Type `conda activate` to activate the (base) conda environment.

Create a Python 3.9.5 environment, and name it whatever you like:

`conda create -n myenv python=3.9.5`

Once created, you can activate and use that Python environment:

`conda activate myenv`

When finished, you can deactivate your environment with:

`conda deactivate`

Any packages you install with `pip` or `conda` will be local to whatever environment you're using, so you don't have to worry about package conflicts. Just don't install everything in your (base) environment, because anything installed in (base) will get copied to new conda environments you create.

Sources:

[Setting up Miniconda on Ubuntu](https://medium.com/featurepreneur/setting-up-miniconda-on-ubuntu-4bf6bece6f9b)

[Conda Cheat Sheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf)

[Anaconda Docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/)

Comment: **+1** for the concept of isolation and using a virtual environment. I however added an answer of what I think a simpler way of doing it on Ubuntu :)

Comment: @Raffa Miniconda/Anaconda has a lot of scientific packages that are not otherwise available on pip.