# Older version of python can't access 'python3-distutils'

Tags: python, python3

**TLDR:** There are two version of **Python** on my system. The older version can't access **distutils**.

I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.
The distro comes with two versions of python already installed: **Python 3.10** & **Python 3.9** and no instances of **pip**.

I've installed **pip** by running:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

That makes **pip** available for **Python 3.10**. I can confirm that by:

```
$ python3.10 -m pip --version
pip 22.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

However, **pip** is not working for **Python 3.9**. See:

```
$ python3.9 -m pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'
```

---

**python3-distutils** is installed (v 3.10 only):

```
$ apt list --installed | grep distutils
python3-distutils/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,now 3.10.6-1~22.04 all [installed]
```

I can't install **python3-distutils** version 3.9:

```
$ sudo apt install python3.9-distutils
E: Unable to locate package python3.9-distutils
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.9-distutils'
```

---

**Question** How to make **distutils** available for **Python 3.9** so **pip** works with the version of Python.

Comment: "Question How to make distutils available for Python 3.9 so pip works with the version of Python." ... Answer: create a virtual environment https://askubuntu.com/a/1348136/968501

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest version of python 3.9.5 on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347748/how-to-install-latest-version-of-python-3-9-5-on-ubuntu-20-04)